# The debugger is not properly installed SSIS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, ssis

I have created Data Integration service project using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10.

I have also created an SSIS solution with a Backup Database Task control flow via a package on it. When I executed the task I get the following error, ( I've created  other tasks, for example send mail, ftp, ... and I see the same error once executed them). Would you please help me to solve this problem?

Error :

> TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
> ------------------------------
>
> Unable to start debugging.
> The debugger is not properly installed.
> Run setup to install or repair the debugger.
>
> ------------------------------
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Unable to start program 'DTS'.
>
> The debugger is not properly installed.  Cannot debug the requested type of code.    > Run setup to install or repair the debugger. (Microsoft Visual Studio Debugger)
>
> ------------------------------
> BUTTONS:
>
> OK
> ------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the file called **Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.exe**

The window should look like the below screenshot. Click repair (make sure VS is closed beforehand). That solved the problem for me.

If you do not have it downloaded. You need it in order to use the SSIS extention.

[Download here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects).

[image]